# How can you move data from column b and append to the end of column a using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have the following dataset.

```
ID  LU  Percent LU  Percent LU  Percent 
239565  7   0.06122 8   0.24489 0   0.69387
241424  7   0.09259 0   0.68518 1   0.22222 
242348  7   0.06451 0   0.80645 1   0.12903 
242349  6   0.14814 7   0.09259 0   0.75925 
242350  8   0.14754 0   0.75409 1   0.09836 
242351  8   0.37037 0   0.55555 1   0.07407
```

In this dataset, the sample ID is in column 1, landuse code is in columns 2, 4, and 6, and percent is in columns 3, 5, and 7.

What I would like to do is change the format of this dataset to only have 3 columns :

- ID in column 1
- LU in column 2
- Percent in column 3

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Thus far, I have tried to append the columns 4 through 7 to the bottom of the columns but I am having trouble keeping the correct sample ID lined up with the relating  landuse and percent.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Paste your current code por favor

Comment: (Pandas)[http://pandas.pydata.org] is very good for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at python's `csv` library? Your data looks tab delimited (although it's spaces now), which the `csv` library can read. You can use `csv.reader` to read each row, and `csv.writer` to write your new output file. Each row read is given as a list, so you can grab that row's value at a column with the column index. So getting the id for a row would be `row[0]`.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
```

I think the only real gotcha in this is that `delimiter` for the csv reader and writer is `\t`, which assumes you're working with tab delimited data (instead of comma, the default).

I'm pretty sure given your question this output isn't what you want (it would just be throwing away the other two LU and percent columns), but it could be modified to do what you want. Inside the loop where each row is read out of the input file, you could write multiple rows to the output.

[python csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)